# Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid bytes32 value (arg="", coderType="bytes32", value="0x6c", version=4.0.37) >

Tags: solidity, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract TestBytes32ToString{
    function bytes32ToString(bytes32 x) public pure returns(uint,uint,uint,string memory){
        bytes memory bytesString = new bytes(32);
        uint charCount = 0;
        for(uint i = 0; i < 32; i++){
            byte char = byte(bytes32(uint(x)*2**(8*i)));
            if(char != 0){
                  bytesString[charCount] = char;
                  charCount++;
            }
        }

        bytes memory bytesStringTrimmed = new bytes(charCount);
        for(i = 0; i < charCount; i++){
            bytesStringTrimmed[i] = bytesString[i];
        }
        return (uint(x),uint(x)*2**(8*0),uint(x)*2**(8*1),string(bytesStringTrimmed));
    }
}
```

When I execute the above code in the new layout of remix，I input "0x6c",then an error had occurred as follws:

```
Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid bytes32 value (arg="", coderType="bytes32", value="0x6c", version=4.0.37)
```

[image]

But I did the same operation in the previous version of remix, it works.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the value has to be 32 bytes long in the new layout, like:

```
0x6c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

From [remix-ide github](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/issues/2194):

> if you specify `bytes32`, then the value has to be 32 bytes long. If
>   you don't mean that, you could use a shorter length, the types
>   `string` or `bytes`.

Duplicated issue with the same question [here](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/issues/2202).

Answer (score -1):

Most of the time we try to provide string but it will be byte32 in following format.
// 'ETH' as a bytes32 string
'0x4554480000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'

Do not forget to remove single cote at the time of input.