# Error: invalid arrayify value when deploying in remix

Tags: solidity

I got this strange error when deploying a contract in remix. Here is the constructor

```
uint256 private value;
bytes32 private itemName;  //<<==cause error
uint256 private itemId;

constructor (uint256 _value, bytes32 _itemName, uint256 _itemId, address _dudes, address _erc20)
```

Here is the error:

```
creation of EscrowTrade1000 errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value="1234", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.0.5
```

Here is the deploying value for the constructor:

[image]

Tried to enter different values for `_ITEMNAME` and the error is the same. What's wrong with the data here?

Comment: There are no `_VALUE`, `_ITEMNAME`, `_ITEMID`, etc in the code that you've posted here, implying that you are trying some other code on remix!

Comment: Hi `goodvibration`, those are the variables passed in to constructor for deployment.

Comment: Not according to the code in your question!!!

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/77069/error-encoding-arguments-error-invalid-bytes32-value-arg-codertype-bytes

Comment: Changing bytes32 to string solves the problem. bytes32 require exactly 32 bytes input.